# How to get values from a returned tuple using OpenPyXL

Tags: excel, python-2.7, tuples, openpyxl

I wrote some code to generate tuples from an .xlsx-file iterating through the columns using the OpenPyXL Library.

```
from openpyxl import workbook
wb = load_workbook('....\example.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SomeMatrix')
c = tuple(ws.columns)
print c
```

Which returns

```
((<Cell u'SomeMatrix'.A1>, <Cell u'SomeMatrix'.B1>, ..., <Cell u'SomeMatrix'.CY1>),...
,(<Cell u'SomeMatrix'.A400>, <Cell u'SomeMatrix'.B400>, <Cell u'SomeMatrix'.CY400>))
```

I would like to pull the values from these multiple columns (e.g. by using cell.value) so that I can get a tuple of tuples called c that should look like this:

```
c= ((1,2,...,1234),(3,5,...,9328),...,(2,1,...,4321))
```

Comment: Thanks for the remark. It is quite similar except that I need to use openpyxl to import the Data from excel.
The rest is just converting to tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having a similar problem here is how I got it done in the end.
Note that I am new to coding in Python so I can't guarantee for this to be an efficient solution. Please do correct me if any of my statements are wrong. Also, feel free to post shorter and/or more efficient solutions.

Using the iter_cols() function returns a generator, which handels single-time iterations quickly as it does not load the data into memory before accessing it. Instead it accesses everything on the fly.

My code now looks something like this:

```
from openpyxl import workbook
wb = load_workbook('Path\to\Matrix.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SomeMatrix')

def iter_cols(ws):                               #define your own iter_cols function which yields the cell values via for loop
  for col in ws.iter_cols():
     yield tuple(cell.value for cell in col)     #the yield statement returns a generator
c = tuple(iter_cols(ws))
```